# Get options from database using php class

Tags: php, theme-development, admin, oop

I want to make a php class that gets an option from the wp database (which is an array of options) and be able to call this class with the name of the option and the class to return the options value.

Does anyone know how would I go about doing this?

EDIT:
I have tried the following code

```
class N_Options {

    function __construct($name) {       
        if(isset($name)):
            $options = get_option(THEME_SPACE . '_options');
            $option = $options[$name];
            echo $option;
        endif;
    }

}
```

And I have tried to call the option using

```
new N_Options('option');
```

This retrieves the option from the database just fine now. However, I think this may be accessing the database too many times as I will be accessing this class over and over for all my options.

Is there a way to store these options inside the class as an array variable and keep calling the class to look inside the variable without calling a new class for each option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have [registered your option](http://queryposts.com/function/add_option/) without setting the fourth parameter `$autoload` to `no` your calls to `get_option` will not trigger any extra database call because all aotoload options are stored in the cache when the site is loaded.

To test it add …

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG',         TRUE );
define( 'SAVEQUERIES',      TRUE );
```

… to your `wp-config.php`, install the [plugin Debug Queries](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-queries/) and look at the real queries.

Comment: Thats great. I never knew they were stored in the cache. Thanks for the help toscho & Ludovic.

Answer (score 0):

look at [Options API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) in wordpress codex,
there is all you need i think...

Comment: I have edited my code above using the Options API. But I think it will be accessing the database unnecessarily too many times.